# Excel 2010 VBA - Copy a formula (with Text) to the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am seeking for an advise. Thanks a lot for any help you may priovide for this issue.

Here is the code I have found. It works well but the formula I need to copy contents "Text" and the routine doesn't want to work. Any idea about what should I do?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("y2:y" & lastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2,Vlook!$C$2:$D$17,2,FALSE),"FOREIGN")"  ' Not Working - The "Text" becomes red in the VBA Editor

      '  .Range("z2:z" & lastRow).Formula = " =VLOOKUP(C2,$U$2:$V$10,2,0)"  'Works well with this formula

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace **"FOREIGN"**  with  **""FOREIGN""**

Answer (score 1):

In order to include a double quote inside a string, you need to type a double double quote, like this:

```
Text = "Here is a text ""TEXT"" enclosed in quotes"
```